# How to update span when text is entered in form text field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like a span to update when a value is entered into a text field using jquery. 
My form field has a text box with the name "userinput" and i have a span with the id "inputval". 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:
although you marked this as the correct answer, note that you should use the keyup event rather than the change event or the keydown**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=userinput]').keyup(function() {
      $('#inputval').text($(this).val());
    });
    });
```

Comment: I guess great minds think alike!  Or maybe it was just really trivial?

Comment: :) it is not a complex problem

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you have to call again `keyup()` to trigger for the last char:

```
$(".editable_input").keyup(function() { 
    var value = $(this).val();
    var test = $(this).parent().find(".editable_label");
    test.text(value);
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.    Be sure that you understand what is going on here.

```
// when the DOM is loaded:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // find the input element with name == 'userinput'
    // register an 'keydown' event handler
    $("input[name='userinput']").keydown(function() {
        // find the element with id == 'inputval'
        // fill it with text that matches the input elements value
        $('#inputval').text(this.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name=userinput]").keydown(
      function() {
        $('#inputval').text(this.value);
      }
     )
})
```

Comment: it is the correct answer, he should use the keydown event rather than the change event.
but you should not reselect he input element again as TM said

Comment: This won't actually work.   `text()` will always return an empty string since the input has no inner text, it only has a value.   Also, there is no need to find the element again, since you already have a reference to it in the event handler (this)